# If $f:X\rightarrow X$ is continuous and $(X,d)$ is compact, show there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $d(x,f(x))>\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

> If $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a continuous function with no fixed points and $(X,d)$ is compact, show there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $d(x,f(x))>\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$.

My hope is to argue as follows, but I seem to be ending up with a slightly stronger statement which is what worries me a bit. Since $X$ is compact we know that $X\times f(X)$ is compact and therefore $d: X\times f(X)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ has compact image. So $d$ attains a minimum, thus there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which $d(x,f(x))\geq \epsilon$ for all $x\in X$. Does this seem ok?

Comment: You need to explain why the minimum that $d$ attains is positive (i.e., not zero).  It's only one short line to do this.

Comment: That's just because $f$ has no fixed points. I left it out as I figured it was obvious, but you're right.

Comment: Your thought seems on the right track; I would just rephrase it a bit. Let $g: X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be given by $g(x) = d(x, f(x))$. Then $g$ is continuous, so its image in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a compact connected set; in particular, it cannot be an interval with an open endpoint at $0$. The no-fixed-points condition also rules out a closed endpoint at $0$, and you're done.

Note that $X \times f(X)$ is *not* the same thing as the set $\{(x, f(x)): x \in X\}$, which is what I think you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is *not* correct. It doesn't follow from your assumptions that the range of $d$ restricted to $X\times f(X)$ is a subset of $(0,\infty)$. You are only assuming that, for each individual $x\in X$, $x\neq f(x)$.

Use the fact that the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}X&\longrightarrow&[0,\infty)\\x&\mapsto&d\bigl(x,f(x)\bigr)\end{array}$$is continuous with compact domain and such that $0$ doesn't belong to its range. So, the range is contained in some set of the type $[\varepsilon,M]$ for some $\varepsilon,M\in(0,\infty)$ (and $\varepsilon\leqslant M$).